# How to use distinct query in meteorhacks:aggregate package at Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have to use the `distinct` query in MongoDB from the Meteor.
So I added `meteorhacks: aggregate`.
However, the usage of this package is too short.
How can I use this package to implement the `distinct` query of MongoDB?

Comment: `distinct` is not part of the aggregation framework. Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `distinct` function is not part of the aggregate framework. It's available as a property of the Mongo collection.

In Meteor, the collection is wrapped by Meteor's implementation, so in order to get the wrapped Mongo collection you can use the `rawCollection()` function.

This function is part of the native node.js MongoDB driver and, following its convention, either takes an error-first callback as its last argument, or returns a promise.

This leads to several ways of obtaining the value.

```
const FooCollection = new Mongo.Collection("foo_collection");
const rawFoo = FooCollection.rawCollection();

// now you have several options to get the data:
// 1. warp the function with Meteor's wrapAsync() to use fibers and use synchronous syntax:
const fooDistinct = Meteor.wrapAsync(rawFoo.distinct, rawFoo);
const values1 = fooDistinct("foo");

// 2. use async/await, if you can:
const values2 = await FooCollection.distinct("foo");

// 3. return the promise if you are in a method, or use the values asynchronously:
FooCollection.distinct("foo")
.then(values3 => {
  // do something with the values
});
```

This involves slightly more advanced topics, and Meteor does not directly handle this for you out of the box, and it might be confusing for beginners.

You will need to understand those topics (`wrapAsync` and `Fiber`s, `async/await` syntax, `Promise`s and their use in `Meteor.method`s) to figure out what's going on.

Comment: It seems to be a good answer.
It is just too difficult for me.
Thank you. :)

Comment: Well, you are trying to do something that is not neatly packaged by Meteor for you. I would recommend you to learn those techniques anyway. I would also advise you to explain what it is that you are trying to achieve in future questions, as those seem like what we refer to as "X-Y questions" (dealing with your specific implementation choice rather than the original intent).